# Selenium Webdriver is not clicking on one element in chrome but same code is working fine in Firefox,why?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate filling of time sheet in a Web application. For that I have a list  of weekend for pending submission like in image:
[image]

And now It take input from the user to select anyone of these weekend and according to user input, web driver will click on selected weekend. Same code is working fine in Firefox but for chrome , I am getting this error
[image]

And this is my code for this task:

```
ArrayList<WebElement> list1=(ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
       //System.out.println(list1.size());
       int count=0; 

       System.out.println("*****************************************************************");
       for(WebElement i : list1) {
           if ("submissionPeriod".equals(i.getAttribute("id"))){
                    count+=1;
                    System.out.println(count+":"+(i.getText())); 
           }
       }

       System.out.println("*****************************************************************");

       if(count==0)
           System.out.println("there is no pending submission");

       else{
           System.out.println("Select one out of these Above Pending Time Sheets for submit or save data automatically....");
           int  input1=isr.nextInt();

           String ele="//div["+input1+"]"+"[@id='PendingSubmission']";
         //  System.out.println(ele);

           wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(ele)));
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(ele)).click();
```

Comment: What is actually this line output `String ele="//div["+input1+"]"+"[@id='PendingSubmission']";`?? could you share??

Comment: and why are you not trying to click directly on `a` element as `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("submissionPeriod"))).click();`??

Comment: also omit this last line of code `driver.findElement(By.xpath(ele)).click();`, FYI `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(ele)))` returns `WebElement` if conditions become true..so you can directly perform `.click()` as mentioned above comment..

Comment: If user give input 1 means for 1st weekend in the list then ele will be //div[1][@id='PendingSubmission'] and this is same for other inputs like 2,3 means if it is then exe will be //div[2][@id='PendingSubmission']

Comment: I got your last msg.So I will omit this last line of code.

Comment: But clicking directly will not resolve my issue. Because issue is that web driver is not able to find element

Comment: No, selenium is finding element, problem with the `click()` .. when it's going to click some other element overlayed on desire element that's why it is unable to click

Comment: Try once as `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div["+input1+"]"+"[@id='PendingSubmission']/div[@id = 'su‌bmissionPeriod2']"))).click();` and let me know

Comment: Saurabh, it's not working. Please check the answer for which I gave +1. Those are working. But I don't want to use javascript. SO i tried your solution once.

Comment: What do you mean its not working?? is there same exception??

Comment: best way try as `List<WebElement> list = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id(‌"su‌bmissionPeriod2"))); Actions act = new Actions(driver); act.moveToElement(list.get(input)).perform(); list.get(input).click();`..

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using java script.

```
    JavascriptExecuter js = (JavascriptExecuter)driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", <your web element>);
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for answer. It is working . +1 for answer.

Comment: please accept this answer so others can see the right answer

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead with `JavascriptExecutor`

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='PendingSubmission']["+input1+"]"));
JavascriptExecuter js = (JavascriptExecuter)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", ele);
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for answer. It is working . +1 for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems with the xpath, as you are using position in it. Using position is not preferable in most of the cases.

Instead of using position in xpath, I would advise to go for index.

```
   String ele="(//div[@id='PendingSubmission'])["+input1+"]";
```

Comment: Hi, it's not working. With this, I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue with firefox driver. [Click Issue.](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1202)

Try this workaround methods.

```
 WebElement elementtobeClicked = driver.findElement(By.xpath(ele));

     //Option 1
     Actions actionDriver = new Actions(driver);
     actionDriver.moveToElement(elementtobeClicked).click().perform();

     //Option2
    JavascriptExecutor jsDriver = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jsDriver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",elementtobeClicked);
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for answer. It is working . but how it is issue for firefox driver ? it is issue for chrome driver.

Comment: Issue persist for some of the version of selenium with Firefox and chrome both.

Comment: Can i use some other chrome driver (with different version) with which this issue can be resolved .